# How will i send nested Json to Rest Api in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to send json data to my rest api.
it works when my "ContactData"  as just 6 items but if it more than 6 item like the way it is, my api will see it as null.

```
var ContactData = {
  'myContactData1': myContactDataItem1,
  'myContactData2': myContactDataItem2,
  'myContactData3': myContactDataItem3,
  'myContactData4': myContactDataItem4,
  'myContactData5': myContactDataItem5,
  'myContactData6': myContactDataItem6,
  'myContactData7': myContactDataItem7,
  'myContactData8': myContactDataItem8,
  'myContactData9': myContactDataItem9,
  'myContactData10': myContactDataItem10,
  'myContactData11': myContactDataItem11,
  'myContactData12': myContactDataItem12,
  'myContactData13': myContactDataItem13,
  'myContactData14': myContactDataItem14,
  'myContactData15': myContactDataItem15,
  'myContactData16': myContactDataItem16,
  'myContactData17': myContactDataItem17,
  'myContactData18': myContactDataItem18,
  'myContactData19': myContactDataItem19,

};
```

if i should reduce "ContactData" to just 6 items, i will work fine

```
Map data = {
   'contact' : ContactData,
  'item1': itemdata1,
  'item2': itemdata2,
  'item3': itemdata3,
  'item4': itemdata4,
  'item5': itemdata5,
  'item6': itemdata6,
  'item7': itemdata7,
  'item8': itemdata8,
  'item9': itemdata9,
  'item10': itemdata10,
  'item11': itemdata11,
  'item12': itemdata12,
  'item13': itemdata13,
  'item14': itemdata14,
  'item15': itemdata15,
  'item16': itemdata16,
  'item17': itemdata17,
  'item18': itemdata18,
  'item19': itemdata19,

};

 //encode Map to JSON
var dataToSend = json.encode(data);



var response = await http.post("v1/add"),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      "securedData": ServiceConnector.securedData,
    },
    body: dataToSend);
```

Comment: There is no reason that your data is not sent to your API. You should debug your API first  with postman or another command line http client

Comment: what is `ContactData`?